# Mysql building query using same column multiple times with different parameters. Use subquery?

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I have the following query which returns the number of appointments that a particular subject has had:

```
select s.last_name, count(c.length)
from data.appointments a, data.subjects s, data.clinics c, research.sublog t
where s.id = a.subject_id and c.id = a.clinic_id and
      s.ssn = t.ssn and a.status = '1' and
      a.appt_date between '2012-10-01' and '2013-09-30' and a.appt_time not like '%01'
group by t.id
```

I would like to have counts for multiple time periods in the same query (add different years or quarters). I believe I would need to use subqueries for this but am having trouble deciphering what conditions to put in each subquery and what needs to remain outside of the subqueries (I have little experience in this area). Is this correct or is there a different method that would be better to use to return such a result? Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want proper join syntax.  Second, the solution to your problem is conditional aggregation functions.  Here is an example:

```
select s.last_name,
       sum(a.appt_date between '2012-10-01' and '2013-09-30') as cnt_2012,
       sum(a.appt_date between '2013-10-01' and '2014-09-30') as cnt_2013
from data.appointments a join
     data.subjects s
     on s.id = a.subject_id join
     data.clinics c
     on c.id = a.clinic_id join
     research.sublog t
     on s.ssn = t.ssn
where a.status = '1' and
      a.appt_time not like '%01'
group by t.id;
```

I didn't make the change, but you should probably have `group by s.last_name` because you have `last_name` in the `select` clause.  And, the filter on `appt_time` doesn't make sense to me.  You shouldn't use `like` on a date/time field.

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a shot. For clarification, the filter on appt_time is due to a certain classification of appointments that are co-treated between two departments that are always scheduled at XX:01, so we want to exclude those to avoid double counting.

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks again!